# Get last character in string

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8.7

I want to get the last character in a string MY WAY - 1) Get last index 2) Get character at last index, as a STRING. After that I will compare the string with another, but I won't include that part of code here. I tried the code below and I get a strange number instead. I am using ruby 1.8.7.

Why is this happening and how do I do it ?

```
line = "abc;"
last_index = line.length-1
puts "last index = #{last_index}"
last_char = line[last_index]
puts last_char
```

Output-

```
last index = 3
59
```

[Ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-slice) told me that array slicing works this way -

```
a = "hello there"
a[1] #=> "e"
```

But, in my code it does not.

Comment: This seems so unintuitive to me. In Java and C#, this never happens.

Comment: Just use `line[-1]`. I’m not sure why everyone’s answering with `line[-1, 1]`.

Comment: Also, your code kinda works, the 'strange number' you are seeing is `;` ASCII code. Every characters has a corresponding ascii code ( https://www.asciitable.com/). You can use for conversation`last_char.chr`, it should output `;`.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
I keep getting constant up votes on this, hence the edit. Using `[-1, 1]` is correct, however a better looking solution would be using just `[-1]`. Check Oleg Pischicov's answer.

```
line[-1]
# => "c"
```

**Original Answer**

In ruby you can use `[-1, 1]` to get last char of a string. Here:

```
line = "abc;"
# => "abc;"
line[-1, 1]
# => ";"

teststr = "some text"
# => "some text"
teststr[-1, 1]
# => "t"
```

**Explanation:** 
Strings can take a negative index, which count backwards from the end
of the String, and an length of how many characters you want (one in
this example).

Using [`String#slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-slice) as in OP's example: (*will work only on ruby 1.9 onwards as explained in Yu Hau's answer*)

```
line.slice(line.length - 1)
# => ";"
teststr.slice(teststr.length - 1)
# => "t"
```

***Let's go nuts!!!***

```
teststr.split('').last
# => "t"
teststr.split(//)[-1]
# => "t"
teststr.chars.last
# => "t"
teststr.scan(/.$/)[0]
# => "t"
teststr[/.$/]
# => "t"
teststr[teststr.length-1]
# => "t"
```

Comment: Thanks. But, can you also show me a solution which uses my logic ?

Comment: line.slice(line.length - 1) - Also gives the same output I was getting. It looks like this is a problem with ruby version < 1.9.x. Also read Yu Hao's answer.

Comment: yeah I read that. Sorry I was on ruby2.0 so could not validate your example.

Answer (score 46):

Just use "-1" index:

```
a = "hello there"

a[-1] #=> "e"
```

It's the simplest solution.

Comment: This is much simpler than others.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Rails, then apply the method #last to your string, like this:

```
"abc".last
# => c
```

Comment: I just found out that chaining last on last does not work. it's not cool even if it would be dirty code doing this I believe. I like your post and benchmarking it just found that deception about the method last

Answer (score 6):

You can use `a[-1, 1]` to get the last character.

You get unexpected result because the return value of `String#[]` changed. You are using Ruby 1.8.7 while referring the the document of Ruby 2.0

Prior to Ruby 1.9, it returns an integer character code. Since Ruby 1.9, it returns the character itself.

[`String#[]` in Ruby 1.8.7](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-5B-5D):

> ```
> str[fixnum] => fixnum or nil
> ```

[`String#[]` in Ruby 2.0](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D):

> ```
> str[index] → new_str or nil
> ```

Comment: I had a feeling this funky behavior had something to with my old ruby version.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In ruby you can use something like this:

```
ending = str[-n..-1] || str
```

this return last n characters

Answer (score 1):

Using Rails library, I would call the method #last as the string is an array. Mostly because it's more verbose..

To get the last character.

```
"hello there".last() #=> "e"
```

To get the last 3 characters you can pass a number to #last.

```
"hello there".last(3) #=> "ere"
```

Comment: This assumes you're using Rails. The question was about Ruby.

Comment: You are right. who does not using Ruby on Rails on every Ruby projects? probably many, but I think there are many better answers already without using rails library.

Answer (score 0):

**Slice()** method will do for you.

For Ex

```
 "hello".slice(-1)
 # => "o"
```

Thanks

Comment: No. It does not help. It gives me 59

Comment: is that really a string..? what does it return if you print this "your string".class ..? String or something else..?

Comment: This is the correct behavior for Ruby pre-1.9. The OP mentioned that he uses Ruby 1.8.7, an old, obsolete, deprecated, unmaintained version.

Answer (score 0):

Your code kinda works, the 'strange number' you are seeing is `;` ASCII code. Every characters has a corresponding ascii code ( https://www.asciitable.com/). You can use for conversation`puts last_char.chr`, it should output `;`.